# How to do with that if I want to pass the data from the input, and also want user can not edit the id input?

Tags: html, django

This is the template html:

```
    <form action="/app02/user_edit-{{obj.id}}/" method="post" >
        <input type="text" name="id" value="{{obj.id}}" disabled>
        <input type="text" name="username" value="{{obj.username}}">
        <input type="text" name="password" value="{{obj.password}}">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
    </form>
```

I have a form in the template, and the input for id I don't want it is editable for user, so I set it to `disabled`, but however if set if to `disabled,` I can not pass the data to the action now.

In the `views.py`:

```
nid = request.POST.get('id') # there will get "None"
```

How to do with that if I want to pass the data from the input, and also want user can not edit the id input ?

please ignore the form tag param's `obj.id`, I just want to pass data from the input.

Comment: The URL itself should identify the object being edited, i.e. something like `/app/object123/edit`.  Otherwise just accept that the user can insert whatever value he likes in the form data, so your form processing should validate that the user has permission to edit the given object id.

Comment: @JohnGordon yes, thanks for reminding.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think instead of 'disabled' try 'readonly' property of html because
A readonly element is just not editable, but gets sent when the according form submits. a disabled element isn't editable and isn't sent on submit.

```
<form action="/app02/user_edit-{{obj.id}}/" method="post" >
    <input type="text" name="id" value="{{obj.id}}" readonly>
    <input type="text" name="username" value="{{obj.username}}">
    <input type="text" name="password" value="{{obj.password}}">
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: A crafty user can still edit the HTML in his browser to remove that property.

Comment: @johnGordon in that case you can use id as hidden parameter

Comment: @JohnGordon Do you have a better method, not to change the id in browser?

Answer (score 0):

Use hidden inputs:

```
<form action="/app02/user_edit-{{obj.id}}/" method="post" >
        <input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{obj.id}}">
        <input type="text" name="username" value="{{obj.username}}">
        <input type="text" name="password" value="{{obj.password}}">
        <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

Comment: A crafty user can view the HTML source in his browser and change the value of `id` to whatever he likes.

Answer (score 0):

You really dont need to show id of any object to user. Instead of text input you should use hidden for this purpose

```
<input type="hidden" name="id" value="{{obj.id}}">
```